# K-algebra isomorphic to a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am trying to understand why this is true:
Let K be a field, and let $K[a_1,\ldots,a_r]$ be a finitely generate $K$-algebra. If $a_1,\ldots, a_r$ are algebraically independent, then $K[a_1,\ldots,a_r]$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the definition of algebraic independence. The set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_r\}\subseteq A$ ($A$ some $K$-algebra) is algebraically independent if $f\in K[X_1,\ldots,X_r]$ and $f(a_1,\ldots,a_r)=0$ implies $f=0$. This is the statement that the unique $K$-algebra map $K[X_1,\ldots,X_r]\mapsto A$ sending $X_i$ to $a_i$ is *injective*. The image of this map, also essentially by definition, is $K[a_1,\ldots,a_r]$, the $K$-subalgebra of $A$ generated by the $a_i$. Therefore this map induces a $K$-algebra isomorphism $K[X_1,\ldots,X_r]\simeq K[a_1,\ldots,a_r]$.